# Projections of a curve in $\mathbb{P^3}$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Given a point $P_0$ and an hyperplane $H$ in $\mathbb{P^3(C)}$, it is possible to define the *projection of center $P_0$ on $H$*:
$$\pi:\mathbb{P^3(C)}\setminus\{P_0\}\rightarrow H,\quad \pi(P)=(P_0P)\cap H $$
where $P_0P$ denotes the line through $P_0$ and $P$.

> Now consider the parametrized curve
>   $$C=\{(s^5,t^3s^2,t^4s,t^5)\in\mathbb{P^3(C)}\,|\,(s,t)\in\mathbb{P^1(C)}\}\,.$$
>   Is it possible to choose the point $P_0$ and the hyperplane $H$ in such a way that
>
> a) $\pi(C)$ is a non-singular conic?
>
> b) $\pi(C)$ is a curve of degree 5 with a singular point of multiplicity 4?

I manage to rewrite $\pi$ analitically, that is
$$\pi(P)=-\frac{P_0\cdot P}{P_0\cdot v}P_0+P$$
where $\cdot$ denotes the standard scalar product and $v$ is the vector perpendicular to $H$. I don't know if it is useful. Anyway how can I proceed?

**EDIT**: for point **a)** I tried to solve the problem. Taking $P_0=(1,0,0,0)$ and $H=\{x_0=0\}$, one should get $\pi(s^5,t^3s^2,t^4s,t^5)=(0,t^3s^2,t^4s,t^5)=(0,s^2,ts,t^2)$. Hence identifying $H$ with $\mathbb{P^2(C)}$ one should get $\pi(C)=\{x_1^2-x_0x_2=0\}$, which is a non-singular conic. Is this part correct?

Comment: Note that $P_0\in C$, so $\pi(C)$ is not defined because $C$ is not contained in $\Bbb{P}^3(\Bbb{C})\backslash\{P_0\}$.

Comment: @Servaes Thank you for your remark! To solve the problem I could extend $\pi$ setting $\pi(P_0):=(0,1,0,0)\in H$: this point can be obtained from $(0,s^2,ts,t^2)$ for $t=0$ (note $t=0$ gives $P_0$ in the parametrisation of $C$).